# Date Table Relationship

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of dates (every date from 2003 to 2035) in my data model but am wondering if I need to create relationship(s) between this and my other data tables, wondered if anyone could please share best practice?

If so, my main table has several columns of dates so which would I link to?

To be honest, I am thinking I shouldn't create a relationship as any filtering of the date table will then only filter my model by which date column I have a relationship with?

I hope all that makes sense. It's more of an abstract question at the moment but my ultimate goal is to create some kind of rolling average.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "any filtering of the date table will then only filter my model by which date column I have a relationship with" - why is that a problem for you?

Comment: perhaps because of how I've set my model up but I have two tables with several date columns in each. the relationship with the date table is filtering through one table to the other, creating undesirable behaviour. Maybe I need to read some more and revisit my model..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practise is clearly to create a relationship between your date table and your data table (fact table I assume). But you have to choose the most relevant column to make your link, knowing that it's preferred to not make multiple relationships between the same tables.

If you have a "snapshot date" column, you could make the link with this one to see the status for that period for example. It really is up to you.

If the filtering is annoying to you, you can always disable it on the visuals.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Possibly I have the wrong fact table but it does seem a little restrictive. Is there an alternative method to working with dates? I have some measures which iterate over rows of dates in data tables and effectively look up dates from the date table, i.e. without a relationship, - perhaps this way?

Comment: I think I've figured out a way around it - create the relationships I need but leave them as inactive, then activate them when I need them via the USERELATIONSHIP function..